Questions about bathroom sink drain and vent
I am doing a bathroom reno and have three questions about venting and drains.
#1 - There was vent left open in the wall. It is on the left facing down. Is it appropriate to just cap that and leave it be?

#2 - I can’t move the sink drain back into the wall. Would it be OK to run a 45 from the floor towards the wall and then connect to a 45 in the wall for the drain? The trap arm would run straight back and connect into the vent with a sanitary tee.

#3 - I vent will be added from the floor below sink. Is it correct to just connect into the vertical stack at least 6” above the sink level with another sanitary tee?

Does "floor below sink" mean " a sink on the lower level"?

The vent in #1 appears to have been for something in the lower level, judging by the hole in the wall plate. can't you tie into that for your new vent?

Yes, there is a powder room almost below and the sink currently uses an  air admittance valve. Since the walls are open I rather connect into the demoed bathroom  vent for a more permanent solution.
I was hopeful to just tie it into the old vent. Unfortunately I can’t connect into it without cutting open drywall below. I rather tie it into the sink because it is the utility closet below and less repair work for the same result.

#1:

"Is it appropriate to just cap that and leave it be?"

You should get rid of it and plug the tee where it originates from.
#2:

"Would it be OK to run a 45 from the floor towards the wall and then connect to a 45 in the wall for the drain?"

YES
#3:

"Is it correct to just connect into the vertical stack at least 6” above the sink level with another sanitary tee?"

YES, but the sani-tee should be installed upside-down, if this is a dedicated vent.

One more question. The vent will ideally will come up next to the left stud on the wall with the flue. I believe it is a class B because it is doubled wall. My understanding is the vent pipe can be within 1” of the flue due to being a class B. There is only 5” of clearance between the stud and the flue. Is this correct?
